# Navbar elements on top of each other instead of spaced out. Display: flex, and space-inbetween

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to space my logo and hamburger menu to either side of the page, with the logo on the left and hamburger on the right. The two elements are either reversed, or on top of each other. I can't even remember all of the things I've tried in order to fix it... it's been hours of reworking.

html

```
            <nav>
              <div id="topNav" class="navigation">
  <span id="closebtn" onclick="navToggle()">
      <span class="line1"></span>
      <span class="line2"></span>
      <span class="line3"></span>
  </span>

<ul class="menulist">
  <li><a class="menuitems" href="project3.html">PUPSPOT</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuitems" href="project.html">POTTED</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuitems" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuitems" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
</div>

<div class="logo">
    <img src="images/madlogo.png"/>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

html,body
{
    background-color: #f7f7f8;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}



body {
    transition: background-color .5s;
}


.container {
  background-color: #f7f7f8;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(1px, auto);
  grid-template-areas:
  "nav"
  "hero"
  "proj"
  "process";
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  grid-area: nav;
}


.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.logo {
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
      width: 4%;
}
```

[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXBm6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so first I would recommend looking at my article for some nice CSS references...

https://medium.com/@hunter.campbell843/css-references-for-new-developers-and-old-6e3dbead437f

Also you just need a justifyContent: space-between attribute on your nav element and to put your "main" element outside your  element. Here's what I did to your code below....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        font-size: 10px;
      }

      html,
      body {
        background-color: #f7f7f8;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
      }

      body {
        transition: background-color 0.5s;
      }

      .container {
        background-color: #f7f7f8;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(1px, auto);
        grid-template-areas:
          "nav"
          "hero"
          "proj"
          "process";
        padding-bottom: 5rem;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 100vh;
      }

      nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between; /*This pushes your child elements to each extreme, what you were missing*/
        align-items: center;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        /* width: 100%; */ /*You're using grid so you shouldn't need this*/
        z-index: 99;
        grid-area: nav;
        
      }

      .navigation {
        /* width: 100%;      Don't need either*/
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        padding-top: 0px;
      }

      .logo {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        /* margin: 0 auto;      Don't need either*/
        /* position: absolute;        Don't need either*/
        width: 4%;

        
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="" />
      </div>

      <div id="topNav" class="navigation">
        <span id="closebtn" onclick="navToggle()">
          <span class="line1"></span>
          <span class="line2"></span>
          <span class="line3"></span>
        </span>

        <ul class="menulist">
          <li><a class="menuitems" href="">PUPSPOT</a></li>
          <li><a class="menuitems" href="">POTTED</a></li>
          <li><a class="menuitems" href="">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a class="menuitems" href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main"></div>  <!--Your main element was inside your nav element throwing everything off-->
  </body>
</html>
```